layer.dart:1068:13: error: the method 'setrasterizertracingthreshold' isn't defined for the class 'scenebuilder'
My team is encountering an iOS error that states: "layer.dart:1068:13: error: the method 'setRasterizerTracingThreshold' isn't defined for the class 'SceneBuilder'." We've spent over three days trying to resolve it without success. Can anyone help us fix this?We've double-checked our Flutter dependencies and ensured we're using the latest stable version. We also ran flutter clean and reinstalled the packages, but the issue persists. It seems like the method in question might be deprecated or not available in the current version of the SDK we are using.
We've looked through the Flutter documentation and GitHub issues, but we haven't found any direct references that specify when setRasterizerTracingThreshold was removed or modified. If anyone else has encountered this problem or if you have any insights, your input would be greatly appreciated.
Also, could it be possible that some of our packages might not be fully compatible with the current Flutter version? We’re using some custom renderers that might depend on older methods. Any advice on how to effectively trace this issue down or alternative approaches to achieve rasterization tracing would be super helpful! Thanks in advance for your support!

can you also add your current setup like the Flutter SDK version?

I had the same problem, I could not solve it, except that, I went back in my work, I redid my coding not this time with copy and paste then by correcting but rather line by line, then I realized that I had forgotten to add a library "import 'package:fluentui...." of course I did that after restarting my android studio and even my pc, and there no more worries, the problem was no more, I do not know if it will help but I just tell what happened to me, good luck

I had the same error. Upgrading to the latest Flutter version (3.24.4) helped me.
